# Almost complex structure commuting with symplectomorphism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a symplectic vector space with symplectic form $\omega$. Furthermore, let $\varphi : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear symplectomorphism. Consider the set
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\varphi} := \{ I \in \text{End}(V) \mid I^{2} = -\text{Id}, I \text{ compatible with }\omega, I\circ \varphi = \varphi \circ I \},
$$
i.e. the set of compatible almost complex structures commuting with $\varphi$. I have now the following questions.

**Questions:**

1. Is this set non-empty? If in general no, what conditions on $\varphi$ are necessary such that $\mathcal{I}_{\varphi} \not= \emptyset$?
2. If this space is non-empty, is it contractible?

Unfortunately, I had no success finding any references. I am hoping some of you could help me out ;).

Greetings,
Helge

Comment: The generic symplectomorphism is taken into a Cartan subgroup by a conjugation, so check the Cartan subgroups. Also, the problem is essentially the same over the complexification, so try the complexified Cartan subgroup first.

Comment: wat do you mean by " taken into a Cartan subgroup by a conjugation"?

Comment: In particular, I am intereseted in $dim(V)=2$

Comment: Recall that every semisimple Lie group has a finite number of Cartan subgroups, so that the generic element $g$ of the semisimple Lie group is conjugate, i.e. has the form $g=hch^{-1}$, to some element $c$ of one of those Cartan subgroups. That is what I mean by conjugate.